# flask sqlalchemy one-to-one relationship issues

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to set up a one-to-one relationship in flask. I have a script that runs `db.drop_all()` when I want to clear my DB. But I am getting cascade errors when doing that. I have played with many combinations using cascade and single_parent arguments in the model relationships and nothing is working. Any help would be appreciated to help set up a one-to-one relationship that will allow me to use `db.drop_all()` without error. Below is my latest iteration.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from project import db, bcrypt


class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), default=True, nullable=False)
    created_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=func.now(), nullable=False)
    profile = db.relationship("Profile", cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")


    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('utf-8')



class Profile(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'profile'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    github_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    user = db.relationship("User")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from project import db, bcrypt


class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    ...

    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('utf-8')



class Profile(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'profile'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    ...

    user = db.relationship(
        'User', cascade='all', backref=db.backref('profile', cascade='all'))
```

note how relationship between the two models is defined in profile model only.

Comment: thank you, will try this when I get home later. Will follow up then.

Comment: I am getting error - Error creating backref 'profile' on relationship 'Profile.user': property of that name exists on mapper 'mapped class User->user'

Comment: I figured it out